# Error TypeScript en VSCode al cerrar archivo d.ts

Tags: typescript, vscode

Estoy fusionando declaraciones (declaration merging) para poder crear valores adicionales en express y express-session.

Tengo preparado mi archivo d.ts, todo parecía ir bien, pero lo gracioso viene cuando cierro el documento express.d.ts, al hacerlo el linter indica que tengo errores justo en los tipos que he declarado. Es como si no lo tomara en cuenta.

Cabe decir que el compilador de typescript no lanza ningún error, pero el tslint si. Si lanzo `tsc --watch`, el proyecto se compila divinamente.

El archivo d.ts en cuestión:

```
import express from 'express';
import session from 'express-session';
import { User } from "../backend/models/classes/user.model";

declare module 'express' {
    export interface Request {
        userType: User['access'],
        isLogged: boolean
    }
}
declare module 'express-session' {
    export interface SessionData {
        user: User
    }
}
```

Dejo mi tsconfig para que veáis si falta algo:

```
    {
      "compilerOptions": {
        /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig.json to read more about this file */
    
        /* Basic Options */
        // "incremental": true,                         /* Enable incremental compilation */
        "target": "es5",                                /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */
        "module": "commonjs",                           /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */
        // "lib": [],                                   /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
        // "allowJs": true,                             /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
        // "checkJs": true,                             /* Report errors in .js files. */
        // "jsx": "preserve",                           /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', 'react', 'react-jsx' or 'react-jsxdev'. */
        // "declaration": true,                         /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
        // "declarationMap": true,                      /* Generates a sourcemap for each corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
        // "sourceMap": true,                           /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
        // "outFile": "./",                             /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */
        // "outDir": "./",                              /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
        // "rootDir": "./",                             /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
        // "composite": true,                           /* Enable project compilation */
        // "tsBuildInfoFile": "./",                     /* Specify file to store incremental compilation information */
        // "removeComments": true,                      /* Do not emit comments to output. */
        // "noEmit": true,                              /* Do not emit outputs. */
        // "importHelpers": true,                       /* Import emit helpers from 'tslib'. */
        // "downlevelIteration": true,                  /* Provide full support for iterables in 'for-of', spread, and destructuring when targeting 'ES5' or 'ES3'. */
        // "isolatedModules": true,                     /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */
    
        /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
        "strict": true,                                 /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
        "noImplicitAny": false,                       /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
        // "strictNullChecks": true,                    /* Enable strict null checks. */
        // "strictFunctionTypes": true,                 /* Enable strict checking of function types. */
        // "strictBindCallApply": true,                 /* Enable strict 'bind', 'call', and 'apply' methods on functions. */
        "strictPropertyInitialization": false,        /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */
        // "noImplicitThis": true,                      /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */
        // "alwaysStrict": true,                        /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
    
        /* Additional Checks */
        // "noUnusedLocals": true,                      /* Report errors on unused locals. */
        // "noUnusedParameters": true,                  /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
        // "noImplicitReturns": true,                   /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
        // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,          /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */
        // "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,            /* Include 'undefined' in index signature results */
        // "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,  /* Require undeclared properties from index signatures to use element accesses. */
    
        /* Module Resolution Options */
        // "moduleResolution": "node",                  /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
        // "baseUrl": "./",                             /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
        // "paths": {},                                 /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
        // "rootDirs": [],                              /* List of root folders whose combined content represents the structure of the project at runtime. */
        "typeRoots": [ "./node_modules/@types", "./@types" ],                             /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
        // "types": [],                                 /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */
        // "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,        /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
        "esModuleInterop": true,                        /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
        // "preserveSymlinks": true,                    /* Do not resolve the real path of symlinks. */
        // "allowUmdGlobalAccess": true,                /* Allow accessing UMD globals from modules. */
    
        /* Source Map Options */
        // "sourceRoot": "",                            /* Specify the location where debugger should locate TypeScript files instead of source locations. */
        // "mapRoot": "",                               /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
        // "inlineSourceMap": true,                     /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */
        // "inlineSources": true,                       /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */
    
        /* Experimental Options */
        // "experimentalDecorators": true,              /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
        // "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,               /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */
    
        /* Advanced Options */
        "skipLibCheck": false,                           /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,        /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
      },
      "include": ["@types/"]
    }
```

Dejo un vídeo del problema para que veáis de qué trata:
https://youtu.be/RX0G7dbNvzk

Casi se me olvida, el error en cuestión que devuelve el linter:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta con

```
declare namespace Express {
    interface Request {
        userType: User['access'],
        isLogged: boolean
    }
}
```

Lo que tienes que aumentar en este caso es el namespace no el módulo

Comment: Sinceramente he tocado algunos parámetros en el tsconfig he se ha solucionado, lo mejor es que después los quité y no ha pasado nada, por lo tanto el problema debía ser de visual studio. Sin embargo después he tenido problemas cuando estaba configurando las rutas, he modificado el archivo como lo has indicado y se ha solucionado, así que te debo una cerveza! 

Comment: Lo he vuelto a comprobar y otra vez da fallo en el middleware, no entiendo nada  las rutas funcionan pero sigue indicando que la propiedad userType no existe en el tipo Request, no sé donde tocar ya para solucionarlo

Comment: Algo que podría ser es que `Request` parece ser también una interfaz global, así que es importante que la diferencies del `Request` global y el `Request` de *express*

Comment: Pero las interfaces pertenecen a los módulos, no? Es decir, si a una interfaz que pertenece a express (request) le estoy definiendo una propiedad extra, estoy afectando exclusivamente a esa interfaz siempre que se refiera a ella dentro del namespace Express, es decir, es como redeclarar parte del @types/express. No sé, es algo que estoy deduciendo sin tener ningún tipo de fundamento, he profundizado más en TypeScript esta última semana, antes casi todo era JS a pelo, corrígeme si me equivoco

Comment: Si si tienes razón, a lo que me refiero es que existe un `Request` global que se accede como `Request` directamente y otro que existe en el módulo de Express, que se accede como `express.Request` es en esa importante diferencia en donde podría fallar tu código en caso de que estés accediendo a la interfaz incorrecta

Comment: Entiendo, confío en que siempre esté haciendo referencia a la interfaz que quiero "modificar", igualmente TS siempre me lanzará un error cuando no encuentre cualquier propiedad. Sea como sea, muchas gracias! Tu respuesta me ha servidor de guía para solucionar esto, llevaba desde esta mañana y no conseguía solucionarlo